# How to best model survey forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create two types surveys, a PreSurvey and a PostSurvey, that users can fill out. Each survey type will always have the same questions. What's the best way to model those two surveys?

Having each survey model have a different field for each question seems like bad design because it's hard to maintain and extend.

I'm trying to create Survey model that has_many questions, and have a PreSurvey and PostSurvey that inherit from it. This seems like it's the right path, but I can't figure out how to force instances of one type of survey to specificy the questions that will always be there. Any time a PreSurvey is created, it will always have the same set of Questions in it. How can I force this behavior?

Sorry that this is less specific than the questions usually asked here, if somebody could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.